# Adding new stylesheet to wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Trying to remove some of the clutter from the child theme 'style.css' file.. So im breaking up the css into multiple files, however.. It doesnt appear to be loading.

```
function building_page_add_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'building-page-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/building.css' );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'building_page_add_styles' );
```

I have a function right above this doing the same thing for the 'styles.css' which works.

Comment: The function have the same name (building_page_add_styles) as the other you mention (style.css)?

Comment: Nope, names are different. I'm viewing the stylesheet in firebug and its showing an empty file. Could this be a caching issue? I've checked on other browsers and it still isnt loading.

Comment: Use wp_register_style instead and then wp_enqueue_style('building-page-style');

Comment: Could be a a cache issue

Comment: Please note that `get_template_directory_uri()` return the uri of the **parent** theme, so if you're using a child theme use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead.

Comment: Yes, I just realized this Vard, Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

This is from my themes folder, Should work. I think you had some wrong syntax

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'building-page-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/building.css' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts');
```

also you dont seem to have tyour .css file in point to a css folder use this if your .css file is in a css folder

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'building-page-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/building.css' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts');
```